# Call `$state.go('tab.events')` with a parameter for query string?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

There is already a setting in `app.js` of an ionic V1 project. Clicking some buttons will assign the `:period` with different values ('Today', 'Tomorrow', 'Weekend', etc).

```
  .state('tab.events', {
    url: '/events/:categoryTitle?p=:period',
    views: {
      'tab-events': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-events.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

And the following code is used to redirect to http://localhost:8100/#/tab/events/ after login

```
$scope.signWithFackBook = function () {
  facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"], function (data) {
    console.log("Info:" + JSON.stringify(data));
    facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(function (token) {
      console.log("Token: " + token);
      $ionicViewService.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true });
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      $state.go('tab.events'); // Need to go to http://localhost:8100/#/tab/events/?p=today instead
    });
  }, function (error) {
    console.log("Error:" + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
};
```

However, I want it to be redirected to http://localhost:8100/#/tab/events/?p=today instead. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending the params in your [$state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#stategoto--toparams--options) request.

You have 2 params
 - categoryTitle
 - period

This is how you do it.

```
.state('tab.events', {
    url: '/events/:categoryTitle?p=:period',
    views: {
      'tab-events': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-events.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

$state.go('tab.events', {
   categoryTitle: null,
   period: 'today'
});
```

Comment: Can I just use `{
   period: 'today'
}` since `categoryTitle` is null?

Comment: Yes you can. But if categoryTitle is sent before and you want it null the next time then you need to send it again.  In short, yes you can do just one param.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, in my example, the second to the last line in your answer should be `p: 'today'` instead?

Comment: Nope. Check your URL. You are writing p=:period. So period is your param. P is just a part of URL. Run it you will get the URL that you want and ask in your question.

Comment: Interesting, I got the url of http://localhost:8100/#/tab/events/?period=today if using `{ period: 'today' }`. Using `{ p: 'today' }` got the expected `http://localhost:8100/#/tab/events/?p=today

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Because, if u check the link that I have attached. You will see that it replaces the parameters with the value s given.

Comment: I tried `{ x: 'y' }` and it didn't generate any query string. `{ p: 'y' }` got http://local....?p=y and `{ period: 'y' }` got http://local....?period=y. It seems only `p` and `period` are accepted.

Comment: Yes, because p and period are in your url. ?p=:period but x is not there. I am saying that your url should be generated as p=today instead of period=today. as  your param is :period and not p